# dynamic form jQuery display

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm trying to make a dynamic form view, but without controllers, only with jQuery, but I don't know how to hide the content of the form.

First of all, I have to choose the type of user for registration with a select html, and depending of the type of user, I want to show diferents input in my form.

So, this is my register.blade.php script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#nextStep').hide();
      $('#type').on('change',function(){
        if ($('#type').val()=='seller') {
          $('#nextStep').show();
          $('#sellerForm').show();
          $('#providerForm').hide();

        }
        else if ($('#type').val()=='provider') {

          //document.write($('#type').val());

          //document.write($('#sellerForm'));
          $('#nextStep').show();
          $('#providerForm').show();

        }


        else{
          $('#nextStep').hide();
        }
      }

        );


  });
```

- nextStep is a divider over the forms.
- Forms id are sellerForm and providerForm.

The problem is that I'm not hiding the 2nd content, so, I'm gonna have 2 or more forms in the same view, also, I can't add more forms.

Comment: I try modifying the script to:

Comment: <script>
        $('#type').change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == 'seller'){
                $('#nextStep').show("seller");
            }
            if($(this).val() == 'provider'){
                $('#nextStep').show("provider");
            }
            else{
              $('#nextStep').hide();
            }
        });
      </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the below JS code,

```
<script> 
$('#type').change(function(){ 
  if($(this).val() == 'seller') { 
    $('#provider').hide(); 
    $('#seller').show(); 
  } 
  else if($(this).val() == 'provider') { 
    $('#seller').hide(); 
    $('#provider').show(); 
  } 
  else { 
    $('#seller').hide(); 
    $('#provider').hide(); 
  } 
});
```

Also, add the below css code,

```
<style type="text/css">
    #provider, #seller {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: it's logically fine, but now it doesn't display anything

Comment: Try to not hide/show nextStep. Please comment out `$('#nextStep').hide();` and `$('#nextStep').show();` and try the above answer